# .NET Convert tags into a map

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dictionary

I need to convert a text which contains tags into a simple map(dictionary). The text looks like this :

```
<tag1>text1</tag1><tag2>text2></tag2>
```

and what I need to have is something like this :

```
Dictionary<string,string> dicTags = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dicTags["tag1"] = "text1";
dicTags["tag2"] = "text2";
```

Is their a simple way to do this if we don't know the tag name in advance ?

Comment: In this link, we know the tag name in advance <Vendor name = "BankRed">. And in my situation, it can change. I can't know the tag name before running the code.

Comment: Sorry, misjudged that. Unfortunatly I can't remove that close vote, but hopefully noone follows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the XML snippet posted is wrapped within single root element so that it makes a well-formed XML, you can do as follow to produce the wanted dictionary :

```
var raw = @"<root><tag1>text1</tag1><tag2>text2</tag2> </root>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(raw);
var dicTags = doc.Root.Elements().ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => (string)e);
foreach(var kv in dicTags)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
}
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I21p1t)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
Key: tag1, Value: text1
Key: tag2, Value: text2
```

Comment: Thanks you exactly what I needed ! I've just release that I've also got once something like this var raw = @"<root><group><tag1>text1</tag1><tag3>text3</tag3></group><tag2>text2</tag2></root>"; And it doesn't go into the <group> tag. Is that simple to modify it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication96
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<root><tag1>text1</tag1><tag2>text2></tag2></root>";
            XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);
            Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            //if each tag is unique
            dict1 = root.Elements().GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => y).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault().Value);
            //if tag names are duplicated then use this
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            dict2 = root.Elements().GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => y).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Select(z => z.Value).ToList());
         }
    }
}
```